# Dialogflow fulfillment : How to send multiple Payload custom Messenger?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Actually, I try to send multiple message with template on Facebook messenger by agent.add(new Payload) on library "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1" like this :

[Message with multiple template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lZqv.png)

When i do this on the dialogflow console, i have no problem, it works :

[custom payload on the dialogflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPGbd.png)

But I can't do it on my function nodejs, I can just send only one payload and no more.
I had try this, but i have no result (except the message : "Test !") :

```
 function test_intent(agent) {
var payloadFacebook = {
  "messages": [
    {
      "facebook": {
        "attachment": {
          "type": "template",
          "payload": {
            "template_type": "button",
            "text": "Can I ask you a few questions?",
            "buttons": [
              {
                "title": "Yes",
                "payload": "Yes",
                "type": "postback"
              },
              {
                "payload": "No",
                "title": "No",
                "type": "postback"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "facebook": {
        "attachment": {
          "type": "template",
          "payload": {
            "template_type": "button",
            "text": "Can I ask you a few questions?",
            "buttons": [
              {
                "type": "phone_number",
                "title": "Yes",
                "payload": "0606060606"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "facebook": {
        "attachment": {
          "type": "template",
          "payload": {
            "template_type": "button",
            "text": "Take that 3",
            "buttons": [
              {
                "type": "web_url",
                "title": " (Théorie)",
                "url": "https://google.fr/"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "source": "facebook",
  "speech": ""
};

agent.add("Test !");
agent.add(new Payload(agent.FACEBOOK, payloadFacebook, { sendAsMessage: true, rawPayload: true }));
```

}

Do you have a solution to send multiple payload custom on nodejs same on the dialogflow console please ?

Thank you

Comment: Seems that this is a [known issue](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/35]) of  Diagloflow, Here I found a [feature request](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/177) to follow this.